# Kinetic energy of a rotating and spinning rod

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics

How to calculate kinetic energy of rod which is rotating about an external axis and spinning about its centre of mass?

**1)** I know how to calculate kinetic energy of a rod if it is not spinning around centre of mass but rotating around external axis

length=l

mass=m

angular speed $\omega=\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}$

[image: non spinnning rod]

$$KE=KE_{translation}+KE_{rotation}$$

$$KE=\frac{1}{2}mv_{cm}^2+\frac{1}{2}I_{cm}\omega^2$$

$$v_{cm}=\frac{3l\omega}{2},     I_{cm}=\frac{ml^2}{12}$$

$$KE=\frac{7}{6}mgl$$

$$or$$

$$KE=\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$$

**I is about axis of rotation**

$$I=\frac73 ml^2$$

$$KE=\frac{1}{2}(\frac73 ml^2)\frac{g}{l}$$

$$KE=\frac{7}{6}mgl$$

**But now if rod is spinning around its com as well as external axis**

**2)** A rod is spinning as shown

in this case im getting trouble

[image]

Comment: just add the two energies

Comment: In the first case, rod is not rotating about its own COM, then it's KE should be zero about COM, but we taken KE about COM by considering angular speed w(omega).

Comment: If the first rod is attached to the axle by a cord, then the angular velocity about the COM is the same as about the axle.

Comment: R.W. Bird , can you explain why angular velocities are equal if cord is attached

Comment: By combined motion, (refer physics.stackexchange.com/questions/546718/…), the answer is 1/2M(3l/2∗w2)²+1/2ML2/12(w21+w22), as w net has components w1 and w2, along two mutually perpendicular axis

Answer (score -1):

To calculate the kinetic energy of the rod with respect to the external spinning axis, consider two parts of the kinetic energy:

1) rotational energy of the entire rod with respect to the external axis (view the entire rod as a point of mass at its center of mass): $$KE_1 = \frac 1 2 (m (\frac {3l} 2)^2)\omega_2^2$$
2) rotational energy of the rod with respect to its center of mass: $$KE_2 = \frac 1 2 I \omega_1^2$$ where $I$ is the moment of inertia of the rod with respect to its center of mass.
Adding them together gives the total kinetic energy.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. By combined motion, (refer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/546718/what-is-the-kinetic-energy-of-a-rigid-body-rotating-about-an-accelerating-axis-n), the answer is $1/2M(3l/2*w_2)² + 1/2 ML^2/12 ( w_1^2+w_2^2)$, as w net has components w1 and w2, along two mutually perpendicular axis.

Comment: @user600016 But I failed to see any difference between the expression you gave and that is in my answer...

Comment: KE2 should be $\frac{1}{2} I (w_1^2+w_2^2)$. Sorry for not formating the expression in the previous comment properly